# How do I escape @everyone in discord.py?

Tags: python, escaping, chatbot, discord.py

I'm developing a [Discord](https://discord.com) bot in Python which outputs text based on user input. **I want to avoid users getting it to say `@everyone` (and `@here`) which would tag and annoy everyone.**

I tried using `\@everyone` which in contrast to `@everyone` does not make the text itself blue, but it *still triggers a ping and highlights the line in yellow*. This does not only happen when I send a message with the bot but also if I use Discord directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I've been using is to insert a [**zero-width space**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) after the '@'. This will not change the text appearance ('zero-width') but the extra character prevents the ping. It has unicode codepoint `200b` (in hex):

```
message_str = message_str.replace('@', '@​\u200b')
```

More explicitly, the discord.py library itself has **`escape_mentions`** for that purpose:

```
message_str = discord.utils.escape_mentions(message_str)
```

which is implemented [almost identically](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/utils.py#L487):

```
def escape_mentions(text):
    return re.sub(r'@(everyone|here|[!&]?[0-9]{17,21})', '@\u200b\\1', text)
```