# Discord.py How do I make my bot not ping everyone when it repeats a users argument

Tags: python, discord.py

Im trying to make a command that repeats what a user says but when people put an @everyone ping in their message the bot pings everyone.
My code:

```
@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, *, arg):
  everyone = ctx.message.guild.default_role
  if arg == everyone:
    await ctx.send(arg.replace('@every-no'))
  await ctx.send(arg)
```

Comment: `discord.utils.escape_mentions`

Comment: Oh, possible [Duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62414347/how-do-i-escape-everyone-in-discord-py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord has a utility function to escape mentions!
[`discord.utils.escape_mentions(text)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.escape_mentions)
Check it out!

You can also make use of the [`AllowedMentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.AllowedMentions) object when sending messages.

```py
allowed = discord.AllowedMentions.all() # Make all mentions escaped. You can always change.
await ctx.send(arg, allowed_mentions=allowed)
```